# Copy all dotfiles except for `.git` and `..`

Tags: bash, wildcards, dot-files

I am aware of using `.[!.]*` to refer to all dotfiles in a directory with the exception of `..`, but how might one refer to all dotfiles except for `..` and `.git`? I have tried several variations on `.[!.||.git]*` and `.[!.][!.git]*` and the like, but none refer to the intended files.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can use the extended globbing in bash:

```
shopt -s extglob
ls .!(.|git)
```

This also matches `.`, though, so you probably need

```
ls .!(|.|git)
```

Comment: http://paste.ubuntu.com/6118550/

Comment: @RahulPatil: So what?

Comment: have you tested with that `cp` to exclude only `..` and `.git` as OP wants

Comment: Thank you. I was able to massage your answer into the following: `ls -la .[!(|.|.git)]*`.

Comment: @RahulPatil: Have *you* tested with the second pattern which excludes `.`?

Comment: @dotancohen: Seems very strange. It does something else.

Answer (score 2):

You can use find :

```
find . -type f '!' -iname ".git" -exec cp -rv {} /dest/path  \;
```

It will search all files in current directory and but not include `.git` as we used `! -iname` ( *where `!` means not equal to*)  then it will copy file  to destination location

**Update**

```
find . -not -path '.' -not -path './.git' -iname '.*'
```

also we can use `-iregex` in find

```
find . -not -iregex '.\|./.git' -iname '.*'
```

both example will refer to all dotfiles except for `..` and `.git` in current path

Comment: Thanks. This does not work, and it took me a long time to figure out why. It turns out that `-iname` relates only to the name of the file, not to any of the names of directories in the files' paths.

Comment: I thought `.git`  was file, and I've also tested with `.git` as file..

Comment: `-not` is a non-standard extension. The standard equivalent is `!` which when on its own like that doesn't need to be quoted in any shell. `-iname` and `-iregex` are also non-standard extensions and  the OP said nothing about preserving a `.GIT` or `.Git` file. Also beware it will still report hidden hidden files in the `.git` directory, and `.` is a regex operator so the last one will also exclude a `./agit` file for instance.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to find all hidden files (which includes the files whose name starts with `.` and those in directories whose name starts with `.` recursively) recursively except for `.git` and any hidden files within, you can do:

```
LC_ALL=C find . -path ./.git -prune -o -path '*/.*' -print
```

To copy those elsewhere, you want to stop `find` searching inside those hidden directories:

```
LC_ALL=C find . -path ./.git -prune -o -name '.?*' -prune -exec sh -c '
  exec cp -Rip "$@" /path/to/destination/' {} +
```

(the `-i` option so the user be prompted when both `./foo/.file` and `./bar/.file` end up copied as `/path/to/destination/.file`).

With the GNU implementation of `cp`, `sh` can be avoided with its `-t` option:

```
LC_ALL=C find . -path ./.git -prune -o -name '.?*' -prune \
  -exec exec cp -ait /path/to/destination/ {} +
```

Those only skip the top-level `.git` directory/file. To skip *any* `.git` file, even those in sub-directories, replace `-path ./.git` with `-name .git`.

Answer (score 0):

In zsh like in the Forsyth shell and derivatives (pdksh and derivatives such as mksh), `.` and `..` are never included in its glob expansions, so to list `.*` files in the current working directory except `.git`, also excluding the special `.` and `..` navigation entries on one column, you can do:

```
set -o extendedglob
print -rC1 .^git(N)
```

`.` and `..` also excluded by default in `bash` since version 5.2 unless the globskipdots option is turned off.  The extended glob syntax there is shaped after that of ksh88, and bash has no builtin command to `print` on `1` `C`olumn and the `N`ullglob option cannot be turned on a per-glob basis with glob qualifiers, so the equivalent would have to be something like:

```
println() { [ "$#" -eq 0 ] || printf '%s\n' "$@"; }
shopt -s extglob nullglob
println .!(git)
```

In older versions, `.` and `..` can be included in glob expansions, unless the dotglob option is enabled and the `.` is not matched explicitly, so in those older versions, you can do:

```
println() { [ "$#" -eq 0 ] || printf '%s\n' "$@"; }
shopt -s extglob nullglob dotglob
println [.]!(git)
```

`[.]` instead of `.` so the match is not *explicit*.

Or exclude them explicitly with:

```
println() { [ "$#" -eq 0 ] || printf '%s\n' "$@"; }
shopt -s extglob nullglob
println .!(|.|git)
```

ksh93 skips `.` and `..` by itself since ksh93u+m 2020-08-09. Since ksh93s, it also has `~(N)` as an equivalent to zsh's `N`  glob qualifier.

```
function println { [ "$#" -eq 0 ] || printf '%s\n' "$@"; }
println ~(N).!(git)
```

In older versions, you can do:

```
function println { [ "$#" -eq 0 ] || printf '%s\n' "$@"; }
FIGNORE=.:..
println ~(N).!(git)
```

Beware though that setting `FIGNORE` means hidden files are no longer excluded from globs, so setting it to  `.:..` has the same effect as setting the `dotglob` option in zsh or bash5.2+.

bash has a `GLOBIGNORE` variable as something similar to ksh's `FIGNORE`, but [its design is pretty broken](/a/279448) so I don't recommend using it.

Of course, you can also exclude them explicitly with:

```
function println { [ "$#" -eq 0 ] || printf '%s\n' "$@"; }
println ~(N).!(git)
```